# Using iframes in tabs: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, tabs

I have a few tabs that include iframes. The iframe in the home tab is loaded and viewed with no problems. The iframes in the other tabs, however, are showing the following errors:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined 
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'col' of undefined
```

The following is a snippet of the code I'm using. The iframe sources are large, that is why Ive replaced them with `....` in the snippet.

The issue is explained in more details (along with snapshots of the errors) on [github here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/5810#issuecomment-221335529).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
<div class="panel-container" style="width: 80%; float:right;" > 

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home Tab</a></li>
        <li><a id="lang_href" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Second Tab</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <iframe src="...." style="width:100%;height:600px;" ></iframe>
        </div>

        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <iframe src="...." style="width:100%; height:600px;" ></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"The issue is explained in more details ... on github"_ The issue needs to be explained here, along with the actual code that is erroring out. You are showing a javascript error but not the javascript code that caused it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I didnt write any JS code, just using a library.